# Visual Studio building in release mode but users get message saying they need debug files

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a super weird problem. I am building a program and I have distributed it after building in release mode (At least is says release mode on the top to the left of the local windows debugger button). However, when my users try to run it, it says that they need vcruntime140D.dll and crtbaseD.dll. I know that this would normally mean that they need the redistributables, but these are supposed to be the debug files. They should not be required to run my release built program. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If you are using some 3rd party libraries, make sure that they are also built for Release mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your Release configuration is actually configured to link with non-debug runtime library. Go to your project's properties, while there make sure that selected configuration is Release, then go to C/C++ -> Code generation -> Runtime library and checks that its value doesn't mention debug.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Thanks everyone. I was using a debug-built 3rd party lib.